# Are comments to answers "monitored", that is viewed?

Tags: support

I got great answers to a question (for loop in irregular time series) some 14 days ago. I added a follow-up question in the comment field to an answer. My question is, what exposure does this comment get, that is, should I expect an answer, or should I create a whole new question to bring it to the top of the stack as it were?

thanks all!

Comment: You are supposed to edit your question post for improvement. If you have another question, ask another one.

Comment: The user that posted the answer will see your comment, but that's pretty much it, as the question won't be bumped to the front page. If you want a broader reach, post a new question.

Comment: Side note: Be very careful with types of "followup question" - something like "you said XXXX - does it mean YYYY or ZZZZ" (clarification to answer) is fine, but "How can I use XXXX in foobar" (new question) is generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 6):

Comments are only "monitored" in a very minimal way on Stack Exchange sites. The original author of the post you comment on will be notified, along with the person you @reply to, if applicable, via a message in their on-site inbox. Other people who view the post might see the comment, but they might not. Commenting does not bump a post back to the active list like editing/answering does.

If you have a clarification to a question that you asked, you should edit it into the question itself to make sure it gets addressed by later viewers. If you have a follow-up question, it's often a good idea to post it as a separate question for maximum visibility if it can stand on its own.

Comment: +1. Original author will be essentially notified *just once*. With current way comments show up in UI there is a good chance people with many incoming comments will miss some comments altogether...